# How do you create a data-frame from NoneType?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm currently using the ffn library to analyze stock data. However, while using one of the functions to get information I've gotten back an object I can't manipulate.

While trying to turn the object back into a pandas data frame i get the error: `Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>`

Is there anyway to read this data type back into pandas?

Comment: This probably means the file doesn't exist or the object has no data. As there's nothing there, you probably want to skip it with something like `if data is None: return`

Comment: @b9s I can visually see the objeect so it does exist, I'm trying to access the results still

Answer (score -1):

From the python docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html

**None**
The sole value of the type **NoneType**. None is frequently used to represent the absence of a value, as when default arguments are not passed to a function. Assignments to None are illegal and raise a SyntaxError.

If you put nothing (the absence of value) inside of DataFrame the DataFrame would be empty.  NoneType means that the object is equal to the singleton None.

So to create a DataFrame from NoneType you could test for None and if the result is True create an empty DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
if result is None:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
```

But probably thats not what you want.  More likely the problem is in your acquisition of the object in the first place.  There is no information in that NoneType object.